# WP .htaccess file - How to deny or allow specific extensions to specific users

Tags: .htaccess

In .htaccess file, is it possible to deny or allow specific extensions (for example .pdf) to some specific users (for example IP address) ?
I don't want to use .htpasswd.

The pdfs are already disallow for all users in /uploads/ directory.
I would like that in a custom admin function in WP back office, some roles (admin ans editor for example) could access to these pdfs to control them.
As I'm pretty sure that using roles is not possible in .htaccess, I wonder if mixing FilesMatch and Ip address is possible :

```
 <FilesMatch '\.(pdf)$'>
  Allow from 90.49.222.111
 </FilesMatch>
```

Comment: You should be able to answer your question yourself ... You ask if that is possible. And what did your attempts show?